# How to bring app to foreground programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I need a solution, how to bring a backgrounded app, what is listening for a signal to foreground, when this signal comes. Does anybody have any idea?

(I know this solution is not common and it will be impossible to put this app into App store. But I need it for an iPad for specific usage and NOT for App Store)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There's no way of doing that, not even in a way Apple would reject it.

Have you thought about notifications? when the signal triggers, you send a notifications, and when the user get that notification the app is opened again!

Comment: the problem is that the app may work without user interraction

Comment: So then Im sorry but there's no way of doing it

Comment: how whatsapp bring the app to foreground?

Comment: Antonio MG how you say there is no way did you check the whatsapp when the whatsapp is in backgroud and call appears the app brings to foregroud ?
Do you have a words for this?