# An event should invoke a method while the app is on Background-iphone

Tags: iphone, background, event-handling, invoke

I need to invoke a method each time an event is occurred even if the application is in the background.
In my case -each time I get a picture from the server I want to present it,
and if the application is in the background I want it to reEnter the foreground and present the picture.

Is it possible? if not, what is the nearest alternative?

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i thnk this is not possible, but use notifications to do this that application will become active when it receive notification.

further see these threads

[iPhone OS 4.0.x - transition from background to foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419559/iphone-os-4-0-x-transition-from-background-to-foreground)

[How to bring app to foreground programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904566/how-to-bring-app-to-foreground-programatically)